# Android Java Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to connect to a database on a remote server.
I have the following code with private details masked:

```
public static void connectToServer () {
        Log.e(tag,"Inside connectToServer");
        String result = "";
        ArrayList toDB = new ArrayList();

        //Assign namevalue pairs to toDB
        try {
            toDB.add(new BasicNameValuePair("A",dta.getA()));
            toDB.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B",dta.getB()));
            toDB.add(new BasicNameValuePair("C",dta.getC()));
            toDB.add(new BasicNameValuePair("D",dta.getD()));
            toDB.add(new BasicNameValuePair("E",dta.getE()));
            toDB.add(new BasicNameValuePair("F",dta.getF()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag,e.toString());
        }

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mydom.com/myFolder/file.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(toDB));
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(tag, "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

My manifest file is as follows:


`< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

In logcat I have the following :


`Inside connectToServer 

java.lang.NullPointerException`

 **Why am I getting a NullPointerException ?** 
Thank you.

Comment: what is `tag` or `dta` and where are they defined?

Comment: Please post what your Logcat says, What is dta?

Comment: Are the objects "dta" and "tag" referencing anything?  Those are the only things I can see that's not being initialized here.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I have defined them as private variables in the class that contains this method.
Kumar I have the relavant logcat entries in my question.
DDV Please refer above

Comment: Could you please post the whole Logcat? The stack trace could be useful here. Which line is specified for the `NullPointerException`? Also, where do you initialize `dta` and `tag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some object you dereference inside the method is null, so it's probably eta.

Comment: let me check and get back to you

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I had not called the constructor. Its working now.

Comment: By the way is there a way to check if I have received the information in the php file?

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely trying to call a method of a non-existent object that you were not successful in creating.

Without the exception handler, you would get the line number where the error occurs in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try actually specifying the type of the `ArrayList`

for example  `ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> toDB = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();`

also make sure tag or dta are actually initialized somewhere (maybe when you delcare them you can go ahead and assign them the empty string. for example: `String tag = "";` or `DTA dta = new DTA();` or whatever dta is.

Comment: Thank you. Please refer to comments above. That was not the problem.